# How to convert Telegram's channel into a group?

Tags: telegram

I've created channel which has some members, but I'd like to convert it into a group instead.

Is there any way of converting existing channel into the group?

My goal is to communicate with members both ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only change the type of a channel (public <=> private).

If your channel doesn't have thousands of users, just create a supergroup and share its joinchat in your channel. (and also you can manually add those who haven't changed their group privacy...but it takes time because of the rate limit of telegram APIs)