# How to export Telegram's member list?

Tags: export, telegram

I'd like to export a list of current members of the channel or group. Is it possible through the UI, alternative client (such as *Bettergram*), [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api) or [Bots API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)?

I've seen this feature on some marketing apps (such as [Telegram Auto](http://telegramauto.com/)), but I prefer to do it on my own.

One of the use cases is when [moving members from channel to the group](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/121530/22759) (without manually clicking all of the members), so the question assumes I've admin rights, but if the method will work for other channels/groups, that's even better.

How such an export can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try Telethon which can extract all the members of a given group and saves it in an SQLite database. You need to be an admin for the channel of course.

You can get it with a method like:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetAdminLogRequest

from telethon.tl.types import InputChannel
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelAdminLogEventsFilter
from telethon.tl.types import InputUserSelf
from telethon.tl.types import InputUser

# These example values won't work. You must get your own api_id and
# api_hash from https://my.telegram.org, under API Development.
api_id = ****** # Your api_id
api_hash = '********************************' # Your api_hash
phone_number = '+989122594574' # Your phone number

client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash)
client.session.report_errors = False
client.connect()

if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter the code: '))


channel = client(ResolveUsernameRequest('tabe_eshgh')) # Your channel username

user = client(ResolveUsernameRequest('amir2b')) # Your channel admin username
admins = [InputUserSelf(), InputUser(user.users[0].id, user.users[0].access_hash)] # admins
admins = [] # No need admins for join and leave and invite filters

filter = None # All events
# param: (join, leave, invite, ban, unban, kick, unkick, promote, demote, info, 
#         settings, pinned, edit, delete)
filter = ChannelAdminLogEventsFilter(True, True, True, False, False, False, False, 
         False, False, False, False, False, False, False)

result = client(GetAdminLogRequest(InputChannel(channel.chats[0].id,
         channel.chats[0].access_hash), '', 0, 0, 10, filter, admins))
##print(result)

for _user in result.users:
    ##print(_user.id)
    with open(''.join(['users/', str(_user.id)]), 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(_user.id))
```

or method like this:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync

api_id = 'FILL REAL VALUES HERE'
api_hash = 'FILL REAL VALUES HERE'

client = TelegramClient('xxx', api_id, api_hash).start()

# get all the channels that I can access
channels = {d.entity.username: d.entity
            for d in client.get_dialogs()
            if d.is_channel}

# choose the one that I want to list users from
channel = channels[channel_name]

# get all the users and print them
for u in client.get_participants(channel):
    print(u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.username)
```

However, first, you need to obtain your **api_id** and **api_hash** using MTProto by logging to **https://my.telegram.org/** with your existing Telegram account and
getting credentials.

---

### Resources:

- **https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon**
- **https://core.telegram.org/api#telegram-api**
- **https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id**

Comment: "You need to be an admin for the channel of course." There is nothing "of course" about it, you can view usernames as a user of a channel manually.

Answer (score 1):

Reviving an old question, but telegram has their own API for this request.

https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.getParticipants

Their example code is as follows:

```
channels.channelParticipants#9ab0feaf count:int participants:Vector<ChannelParticipant> chats:Vector<Chat> users:Vector<User> = channels.ChannelParticipants;
channels.channelParticipantsNotModified#f0173fe9 = channels.ChannelParticipants;
---functions---
channels.getParticipants#77ced9d0 channel:InputChannel filter:ChannelParticipantsFilter offset:int limit:int hash:long = channels.ChannelParticipants;
```